How do I inspect a file in Flutter's Application-Documents-Directory?
After writing the file counter.txt
Future<File> get _localFile async {
  final path = await _localPath;
  return File('$path/counter.txt');
}

located in a folder specified by getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() from the path_provider package,
I'd like to inspect while debugging/testing the contents of this txt/JSON file?
For a trivial (counter.txt, counter.json) example, I don't need to look at the file, but when a more substantial state is saved, I'd like to inspect the file occasionally to make sure everything looks right.
How do I inspect a file in Flutter's Application-Documents-Directory?
I see that there is a solution when developing using Android Studio. What is the equivalent when developing using Visual Studio Code for macOS — possibly by launching Xcode for this one function.
